# What types of ahadith do scholars derive fiqh from?

Tags: usool-ul-fiqh, uloom-al-hadith

There are many ways to classify ahadith. One method is by authenticity: is it saheeh (authentic beyond question), hassan (good), da'eef (weak), or mawdoo' (fabricated?)

In [my answer on another question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/4117/7), I mentioned a hadith that's recorded in At-Tirmidhi, which is Hassan (according to my source). Although that example did not have a hadith which scholars derived a ruling from, it raised this question:

**What kinds of ahadith do scholars derive fiqh from, in terms of authenticity?**

I'm not interested in that discussion about tawaatur, so please don't mention that in your answer.

Comment: Are you asking for a minimum requirement?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 2):

There is no consensus as to exactly which hadiths are to be used to derive *fiqh*; that's one of the reasons (but hardly the only one) the *madhahib* are so often disparate in their rulings.

While the four major Sunni *madhahib* accept Sunnah as one of the major sources of Islamic law, second only to the Qur'an, they differed on exactly which *ahadith* properly reflected this Sunnah:

- **Hanafi**: Not only did a *hadith* need to be *sahih*, it also needed to be *mash'hur*.
- **Maliki**: Even *sahih* hadith could be rejected if they conflicted with customary practice of Medina.
- **Shafi'i**: Only *sahih* hadith were to be used; no other conditions.
- **Hanbali**: Only *marfu'* hadiths were to be used (even if they weren't *sahih*); *da'if* hadiths in general were also used in preference to *qiyas*.

This doesn't even get into the minor or non-Sunni schools, not to mention those scholars who follow no single *madh'hab*.  And, of course, any two scholars can disagree on whether any given hadith is even *sahih* in the first place.

<sup>*Primary reference: The Evolution of Fiqh, by Dr Bilal Philips*</sup>

Comment: Well honestly AFAIK what you say about Maliki and Shafi'i school is too superficial. Because Maliki have a very detailed way for what kind of customary practice of Medina is stronger then **ahad** hadith, because sahih hadith according to Maliki school is at least mash'hur and this is always higher then customs of ahl al-Madina! And i guess that all schools more or less accept marfu' and mursal ahadith with some details for each school!

Answer (score -1):

Scholars use only authentic hadith for fiqh. But problem is that each scholar has different method for determining if a hadith is authentic or not. a specific hadith is authentic in view of a scholar but is not authentic in view of another scholar and this leads to different fatwa about the same Islamic question. For example a scholar may consider any hadith in Bukhari hadith collection as authentic but another scholar may disagree this.

*Authentic hadith is authentic only for scholar(s) who consider it authentic and not for all scholars.*

---

**References and more study:**

[THE SHARI‘A](http://www.islamic-laws.com/shariasources.htm)

[Importance - Basics of Fiqh](http://www.islamic-laws.com/impoffiqh.htm)